# thread dump explanation

Tags: java

In the following java thread dump:

> A fatal error has been detected by the
>   Java Runtime Environment:
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>   (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8fd97c,
>   pid=5528, tid=6952
>
> ... ... ... j 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+30
>   j 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
>   j 
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+59
>   j 
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+28

Can someone explain what do the numbers at the end of each line (V+59, +V+30...) mean ?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you please inform which JVM you are using? Vendor, version, OS and arch would help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates you have a bug in your JVM.  I suggest you try Java 6 update 23, or a bug in a JNI library you are using which is corrupting the memory.

The V+59 means the location in the compiled native code for this method where the illegal access occurred (and is next to useless)